# How to create mock data in store proxy of ExtJS

Tags: rest, extjs

Here is the code for get data using REST API
and the REST API will return the array of objects like

```
items = [  
  {id: 1, group: group1},  
  {id: 1, group: group2}  
]
```

But while waiting for the REST API(url: '/api/group')  I want to mock the data   so I can continue with my task but don't know how. Is there anyway that I can   have items in the proxy instead of url for now.
Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Ext.define('Console.store.Groups', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Console.model.Group',
    autoSync: false,
    buffered: false,
    pageSize: 1000,
    autoLoad: false,
    autoDestory: true,
    purgePageCount: 3,
    sorters:[{
        property:'name',
    }],
    trailingBufferZone: 100,
    proxy: {
        simpleSortMode: true,
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/api/groups',
        reader:  {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why won't you just use [memory proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory) in the meantime?

Comment: Thanks. Using memory proxy works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using memory proxy is worked in this case. Below is the code using memory proxy 
How to make the POST(add new group), PUT(update the group), DELETE(remove group)
to work with this memory proxy.
Below is the code to use memory proxy instead of url (REST API).

```
var  data = [  
  {id: 1, group: group1},  
  {id: 1, group: group2}  
];

Ext.define('Console.store.LDAPGroups', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Console.model.LDAPGroup',
    autoSync: false,
    buffered: false,
    pageSize: 1000,
    autoLoad: false,
    autoDestory: true,
    purgePageCount: 3,
    sorters:[{
        property:'label',
    }],
    trailingBufferZone: 100,
    proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                enablePaging: true,
                data: data,
                reader: {
                    type: 'array'
                }
            }
    // proxy: {
    //     simpleSortMode: true,
    //     type: 'rest',
    //     url: '/api/groups',
    //     reader:  {
    //         type: 'json',
    //         root: 'data',
    //         totalProperty: 'total'
    //     }
    // }
});
```